# Exclude .stories and stories.d from npm package using Vite

Tags: vite, storybook

Building a components library and realized that the package included both the stories and it's .d file.
Changed the glob to exclude this but the .d file is till added. What am I doing wrong?

Tested with [glob-tool](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=true&glob=stories%2F%2A%2A%2F%21%28%2A.stories.d%7C%2A.stories%29.%7Bts%2Ctsx%2Cjs%2Cjsx%7D&matches=false&tests=stories%2Fworld.ts&tests=stories%2Fworld-test.js&tests=stories%2Fworld-test.jsx&tests=test.js&tests=stories%2Fbar.tsx&tests=foo.stories.tsx&tests=stories%2Fworld.stories.d.jsx&tests=stories%2F&tests=stories%2Fteeeee%2Fsdf%2Ftest.stories.tsx) and it matches.

Vite.config.ts:

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts'
import {libInjectCss} from 'vite-plugin-lib-inject-css'
import {extname,relative,resolve} from 'path'
import {fileURLToPath} from 'node:url'
import {glob} from 'glob'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(),libInjectCss(),dts({include: ['stories']})],
  build: {
    copyPublicDir: false,
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname,'stories/main.ts'),
      formats: ['es'],
      name: "components-lib",
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react','react/jsx-runtime'],
      input: Object.fromEntries(
        glob.sync('stories/**/!(*.stories.d|*.stories).{ts,tsx,js,jsx}').map(file => [
          relative(
            'stories',
            file.slice(0,file.length-extname(file).length)
          ),
          fileURLToPath(new URL(file,import.meta.url))
        ])
      ),
      output: {
        assetFileNames: 'assets/[name][extname]',
        entryFileNames: '[name].js',
      }
    }
  },
})
```

[image]

Comment: Got  help: glob.sync('lib/**/*.{ts,tsx}', { ignore: 'lib/**/*.stories.tsx'})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set your dts plugin to include stories.

Rather, you should exclude them:

Example:

```
plugins: [
  dts({
    exclude: ['**/*.stories.tsx']
  })
],
```

Comment: True, but my code points to the folder stories not the files. But in combination with your code this also helps, beaside the comment I wrote above. Will accept your awnser because do fix the issue :). Thx mate!